# Drupal url alias and views and clear urls for taxonomy issues

Tags: drupal-6, url-rewriting, drupal-views

I am using views module. I have created blocks using views and a url using page display. This is for taxonomy. So my views url looks like this "news/science" So if someone click on the link he should be taken to www.example.com/news/science. However i am taken to a unstyled page with broken links. But when i try to use the url www.example.com?q=news/science i am taken to a proper page with correct data. 
The issue is only with taxonomy related terms.

i.e all urls www.example.com/news/technology , www.example.com/news/sports appear broken and unstyled however if i manually visit www.example.com?q=news/technology and www.example.com?q=news/sports i am taken to a proper page.

Can anyone suggest what could be the reason.

The same issues is with admin login and logout. If i use www.example.com?q=user and try to login i can login. Also if i use www.example.com?q=logout i can logout. But if i use clean url aliases ie. www.example.com/logout then i am taken to access denied page.

Comment: The clean url issues is only with selected urls. That for all taxonomy related pages, i have around 12 categories under news taxonomy, so total 12 pages , and at admin side only for login / logout and create stories. Rest all links with clean urls works fine. Does anyone have any suggestion on where the issue might be??

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Path module enabled? Thats the module responsible for mapping ?q=logout to /logout.

See here: http://drupal.org/handbook/modules/path

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed anything in .htaccess? any mod-rewrite changes that might be skipping over those particular urls?

Comment: @mixologic..No have not changed anything...It is the same..Works on localhost...The file on localhost, i replaced with that on server, but it still gave me errors..

Comment: Hmm... perhaps mod_rewrite isnt installed on your server? you can create a file in the same directory as index.php, call it phpinfo.php, and put the following in it: <?php phpinfo() ?> and go to yoursite.com/phpinfo.php and it should display a whole host of configuration options.. look on that page for mod_rewrite and make sure apache has that set up..