# Drupal 6.15 clean urls donot work for all

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

HI all, 
I had posted a query here. [Drupal url alias and views and clear urls for taxonomy issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719456/drupal-url-alias-and-views-and-clear-urls-for-taxonomy-issues) But i think i need to be more specific.

The issue is that after upgrading drupal from version 5.1 to version 6.15 and enabling clean urls, most of the urls work however some URLS such as admin login/logout and taxonomy related pages do not work.

I have search on drupal and google. Most of the issues reported are of clean urls completely not working. However i have clean urls but that works partially..

Any suggestion on this highly appreciated. And sorry for ambiguous posts.

**edit**: If i try a url http://www.example.com/node/add/story then i get a access denied page. But if i try http://www.example.com?q=node/add/story i am taken to a correct page. Also if i need to logout, http://www.example.com/logout takes me to access denied page but if i try http://www.example.com?q=logout i am successfully logged out.

**UPDATE**
The issue is still not solve. I am still not sure, what could be the problem.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific on which URLs do not work? Also, do their 'non-clean' counterparts work? (e.g. `index.php?q=admin`)

Comment: Did you try to clear the cache? Do you have any URL-related modules installed?

Comment: yes..Non clean countparts do work..For example... www.example.com?q=node/add/story works but www.example.com/node/add/story gives an access denied page. Also, www.example.com/node/add/poll works fine.

Comment: @fabian...I tried clearing cache, disabled css and js compression. Nothing helped. I hava installed pathauto module. I am a bit confused as to why most of the urls work but only some do not work...I am using views and panels modules as well..

Comment: If you get access denied, try to rebuild permissions. Do you have any access control modules installed?

Comment: @fabian No, i dnt have any access control modules. I have tried rebuilding permissions. Also a point to note here is that there are only specific links which work only with unclean urls. And using clean urls gives access denied error.

Comment: You should carefully (re)check your rewrite rules (in the .htaccess files, and also in the vhost/webserver configuration). From Drupals point of view, a clean URL should be exactly the same as the `?q=` counterpart, as the rewriting happens before Drupal even 'sees' the URL (in other words, Drupal does not know anything about the clean URL in the first place). When you upgraded to 6.15, did you change your server or server config?

Comment: In other words, e.g. 'logout' will normally be rewritten to 'index.php?q=logout' _before_ Drupal comes into play. If the latter works when used directly, the former must be rewritten to something else to cause Drupal to issue a 403. (If you use Apache, you might want to temporarily enable rewrite logging to troubleshoot - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog )

Comment: @Henrik Opel Thanks a lot for a quick reply..I will check for mod_rewrite and see what i can do. Also i have a question that, why only drupal clean urls fail for logout and taxonomy related pages. Rest all work fine. I have not done any server changes though i will confirm this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @noobcode: The partial failure is the strange thing about this - otherwise I would be sure that your rewriting is messed up. But with this, there would need to be a pretty strange rewriting rule in place to have only partial effect.

Comment: BTW, have you checked the watchdog log? If Drupal issues an access denied, it logs it there, along with the contents of `$_GET['q']`, so this would show what the rewriting rules produced.

Comment: @Henrik Opel i checked the watchdog log and i get location as http://www.example.com?q=node/add/story and message as node/add/story. But i am not sure as to what to do. This issue is only for some urls. Mostly for logged in users. Anything else i am missing out?/

Answer (score 0):

Is "Clean URLs" set to "Enabled" in `admin/settings/clean-urls`?

Answer (score 0):

turn off directory browsing in your `.htaccess` file by writing:

```
Options +Indexes
```

instead of

```
Options -Indexes
```

http://drupal.org/node/134440

Comment: Hi, corbacho..thanks for your reply..I tried changing the htaccess values, to Options +Indexes, but it did not help. I tried clearning cache, enabling and disabling clean urls but still got access denied page for certain urls.